# How do I configure an OS X NSWindow as full screen - without using the Lion Fullscreen style?

Tags: objective-c, macos, fullscreen

I'd like to implement two full-screen modes on my OS X app, I've hooked up the window to use the Lion Fullscreen window API, but I also want to allow users to get a fullscreen experience on one monitor, without losing screens in a multi-screen setup.

Is this simply a case of hiding the titlebar and sizing to the active display dimensions manually, or is there a api/library I can use (eg. that has a nice animated transitions)

Thank you.

Please excuse me if this a duplicate, I could only find references to Lion's fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one other possibility for making an application "Full Screen", [Kiosk Mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html).  It disables the status bar, the dock, and if necessary, the option to quit or minimize the window.  Present a window in kiosk mode, then call `-setFrame:display:animate:` and voila!  A fullscreen application without the fullscreen API.